# Error while running rails on remote host. "Could not find crack-0.1.8 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to deploy my rails app that is working fine on my local machine , to a remote host. I am using railsplayground.com to be exact. When I try to run the app using Passenger,I get this error

**"Could not find crack-0.1.8 in any of the sources"**

But when I did a,

$gem list

the gem , crack (0.1.8) is present. I am using Rails 3 btw.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Gem is installed via Bundler. Check your `Gemfile` and see if the gem is listed.
Then, when deploying the application, make sure to execute the `$ bundle install` command.

If you deploy the project with capistrano, you can use the default bundler recipe by including the recipe at the top of your deploy.rb file.

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```